# boost property tree cannot read multiple json data in one file

Tags: c++, json, parsing, twitter, boost-propertytree

I really need to get help to decide my problem. I am using **boost property tree to parse twitter messages** that is stored in json file.  All messages are saved in one json file and I need to parse all one by one.

Here is the twitter json data saved in a file. it has 3 different messages. *(Below is deducted message only for test)*

```
{"id":593393012970926082,"in_reply_to_status_id":1,"user":{"id":2292380240,"followers_count":2},"retweet_count":0}
{"id":654878454684687878,"in_reply_to_status_id":7,"user":{"id":2292380241,"followers_count":4},"retweet_count":5}
{"id":123487894154878414,"in_reply_to_status_id":343,"user":{"id":2292380242,"followers_count":773},"retweet_count":654}
```

And here is my C++ code for parsing the message, using property tree.

```
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::property_tree;
string jsonfile = "./twitter.json"; 

int main()
{  
    ptree pt;
    read_json( jsonfile, pt );
    cout<<"in_reply_to_status_id: "<<pt.get("in_reply_to_status_id",0)<<"\n";
}
```

I want to get all **in_reply_to_status_id** values from the file. Now it is printing only the first line value. The result is printing follow.

**in_reply_to_status_id: 1**

I would like to get all values like below.

**in_reply_to_status_id: 1**

**in_reply_to_status_id: 7**

**in_reply_to_status_id: 343**

How can I get all values from the file. 
Please help me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You should have right json file, for example like this

```
[
   {"id":593393012970926082,"in_reply_to_status_id":1,"user":{"id":2292380240,"followers_count":2},"retweet_count":0},
   {"id":654878454684687878,"in_reply_to_status_id":7,"user":{"id":2292380241,"followers_count":4},"retweet_count":5},
   {"id":123487894154878414,"in_reply_to_status_id":343,"user":{"id":2292380242,"followers_count":773},"retweet_count":654}
]
```

And code should be like this

```
for (const auto& p : pt)
{
   cout << p.second.get("in_reply_to_status_id",0) << endl;
}
```

Instead of `range-based for`, you can use `BOOST_FOREACH` for example.

```
BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type& p, pt)
```

Comment: hello ForEveR.Thank you for your quickly response. Could you also help me to use BOOST_FOREACH for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can see my example, first you should get the child tree, and then parse it. My code:

```
string str = "{\"key\":[{\"id\":1}, {\"id\":2}]}";
stringstream ss(str);
boost::property_tree::ptree parser, child;
boost::property_tree::json_parser::read_json(ss, parser);
child = parser.get_child("key");
for(auto& p : child)
    cout << p.second.get<uint32_t>("id") << endl;
```

I hope this can help you.